# Remove question mark added to url using form 'get' method

Tags: php, forms, .htaccess, url, get

I am using a form and the 'get' method to offer users a return option to an unknown url that they came from within my site, as per the code below. I prefer this to just the browsers back button and it works without javascript.

The problem I am having is that some browsers (chrome, safari, there may be others) are adding a question mark to the end of the url they are referred back to. I don't want this for seo reasons.

My question is either:

1) Can I prevent the question mark within my php code somehow; or

2) Please could somebody show me how to redirect the url using htaccess, I potentially have urls that could end:-

```
.html?

.htm?

.php?

/?
```

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
if (isset ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ) {
$url = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
echo '<br /><form action="' . $url . '" method="get">
<div id="submit"><input type="submit"  value="Return to previous page" /></div>
</form>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Don't use the referer. it's frequently wrong/forged and generally outright unreliable.

Comment: Even within my own site? I haven't noticed it to be wrong so far.

Comment: Marc B is correct.  In general, you cannot trust HTTP_REFERER.  IMHO...

Comment: @martin: maybe not in your browser, but referers are generally shut by various internet privacy packages, url anonymizers, etc... just because you're not using them doesn't mean others won't be.

Comment: okay, thanks Marc B, presumably there is no reliable way to do it then when javascript is off, just the browsers back button?

Comment: Just an annotation: I would be really surprised if if would cause any SEO issues to have URLs end with "?" and no querystring parameters after that. All relevant search engines will know how to handle that without causing duplicate content issues. Technically speaking that may be two different URLs, but search engines are built to work with the chaotic web we all live in ;)

Comment: @BlaM don't overestimate search engines, check if it is true, I have been surprised on several occasions

Answer (score 6):

The `?` probably gets added because you're doing a `GET` request from a form.

Why not do something like:

```
<input type="button" onclick='document.location.href=<?php echo json_encode($url);?>'>;
```

Comment: thanks, but I particularly want it to work without javascript

Comment: Well, you could always use `POST` :/

Comment: You are correct that GET causes the question mark. I wasn't sure about using POST. Could there be an issue if the destination page already has a POST form for another purpose?

Comment: No, it shouldn't cause an issue but it's not exactly pretty either.

Answer (score 2):

use `POST` method instead of `GET`

Answer (score 0):

Is it pertinent that you use a form for this? Why not use a hyperlink and style it to look however you want with CSS?

You could use try using a button instead of creating an input value that will be passed.

```
<form action="url" method="get">
    <button type="submit">Return to previous page</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I don't know the url in advance?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of posting to random URLs (which is not really a good idea) consider using redirects

A solution would be

```
<?php
if (isset ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ) {
$url = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
echo '<br /><form action="redirect.php" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="'.$url.'">
<div id="submit"><input type="submit"  value="Return to previous page" /></div>
</form>';
}
?>
```

then in redirect.php

```
<?php
if (isset ($_GET['return'] ) {
    $url = $_GET['return'];
    header('Location: '.$url, true, 303); // or 302 for compatibility reasons
    echo '<a href="'.htmlspecialchars($url,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8').'">Continue</a>';
    exit;
}else{
    echo 'Error, no redirect specified';
}
```

you can replace `action="GET"` and `$_GET` with `action="POST"` and `$_POST` and it will work the same.

or simply

```
if (isset ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ) {
    $url = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
    echo '<a href="'.$url.'">Return to previous page</a>';
}
```

both will still create a new history entry in the browser.

Answer (score -1):

In the htaccess you should have something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^myPage-([a-zA-Z0-9_]*).html myPHPfile.php?var=$1
```

By the above piece added to your htaccess, when a URL like `myPage-whatever.html` is called, it's just like calling `myPHPfile.php?var=whatever`

Comment: ... which does totally not help answering the question. Yes, that's how you use RewriteRules, but it does absolutely nothing to remove question marks from the end of the called URL.